# What is USB Flash Drive Read Speed?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, memorystick

I know that copying data from a USB Flash Drive to another drive refers to Read Speed. But when I googled for it now, I've come across many websites that say the Read Speed is how long it takes to "pen" a file from that USB Drive, which I do not understand at all. Do they refer to the time from clicking a file to get it displayed on the screen? What does mean when the USB Drive has a 60MB read speed? I wish someone could tell me what exactly a read speed is with examples.

Comment: Where did you see Reads speed as related to open speed? No such thing.

Comment: https://www.flashbay.com/blog/usb-read-and-write-speeds

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you tell me what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting sanDisk customer service and asking them about it, they responded that it's all about transferring data between the USB flash memory and other devices. Data transferred from USB flash drive to another drive is considered reading, and moving data to the USB flash drive is writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have found a badly-written article :
 [What are USB Read and Write speeds?](https://www.flashbay.com/blog/usb-read-and-write-speeds),
which says:

> In other words, how quickly the Flash Drive can Read (open) or Write (save) the data per second.

The article only tries to draw some parallel between the typical entries that you
will find on the menu of some programs. When you use "Open" then this is for reading,
and when you use "Save" then this is for writing.

That's all. Read/Write speeds are still only the time a given number of bytes
is transferred per second.

Comment: Could you provide me with a resource that defines Read/Write speed as you stated, please?

Comment: "Speed" is also called [Data transfer rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_performance_characteristics#Data_transfer_rate).